# Как вывести данные с базы по ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Люди добрые, помогите написать простой код чтоб выводить записи по ajax на ту же страницу где и форма в laravel

Comment: --->laracast.com

Answer (score 1):

Ответ получим на JSON.

```
    $.ajax({
  url: '/post/ajax',
  method: 'get',            
  dataType: 'json',           
  success: function(data){   
  //data - Содержит ответ - массив в JSON
  } });
```

В контроллере (к примеру получить всех пользователей)

```
   public function getAllUser(){
        return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
    }
```

Так же пропиши роут и токен в ajax запросе.

Comment: Работает и возвращает ответ всех пользователей в json
Но как вывести данные на эту страницу в div ?
К примеру чтоб перебрать массив

Comment: @АлексейНазаров через JS, в теле AJAX запроса: `success: function (response) { let users = response.data; }`